# Returning array of JSONs by PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-11

I am trying to get array of JSONs via using query below. But the result is array of tuples. How can I get rid of parantheses which covers each dictionary element and make the result array of dictionaries?

```
SELECT row_to_json(foo)
FROM
(
    SELECT ilce, mah, phone 
    FROM ilan 
    LIMIT 5
) as foo;
```

Query above generates the first result. How can I get the second one?

**First Result:**

```
[({'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308635664'},), ({'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05417411067'},), ({'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05536253236'},), ({'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308776153'},), ({'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308635664'},)]
```

**Second one:**

```
[{'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308635664'}, {'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05417411067'}, {'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05536253236'}, {'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308776153'}, {'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'phone': '05308635664'}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_agg()` and `to_jsonb()`

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(foo))
FROM
(
    SELECT ilce, mah, phone 
    FROM ilan 
    LIMIT 5
) as foo;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8d2268479269b54f8e3a70748c4d6f2)

Comment: Thanks. But need a little tweaking. Now the result is `[([{'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'phone': '05308635664'}, {'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'phone': '05417411067'}, {'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'phone': '05536253236'}, {'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'phone': '05308776153'}, {'mah': 'mehmet akif ersoy mh.', 'ilce': 'esenyurt', 'phone': '05308635664'}],)]`

It can be get by result[0][0][actual index]. But how can I get rid of these first two zero indexes.

Comment: This query does exactly what you want: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f8d2268479269b54f8e3a70748c4d6f2 if you get a different result there must be something else involved which you are not telling us